# Does making a mistake mean you lose your cert?

Tags: faa-regulations, safety, pilot-certification

Disclaimer: I haven't been in, nor do I plan on having an accident. That said, this has always been a question of mine.

Let's say I'm flying a little Cessna or ultralight around Ohio. Maybe the wind is stronger than expected aloft and I run out of gas before making it back home. Clearly I need to put it down on a road or field if I can.

After this happens, does the FAA revoke your certificate?

Comment: [Closely related](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/33856/62)

Comment: [If you're a US Senator](http://www.thesmokinggun.com/documents/bizarre/inhofe-scared-crap-out-airport-workers-192645), you can land on a closed runway, "sky hop" over the construction workers on that runway, and land again and not lose your certificate.

Comment: I have read that if you run out of fuel you can forget ever getting insurance. Don't know how accurate that is.

Comment: *"Clearly I need to put it down on a road or field if I can."* To keep this hypothetical scenario from becoming reality, you can keep track of your [radius of range](https://blog.aopa.org/aopa/2018/04/05/radius-of-range/). Yes, I like that concept. Basically, always know for how much longer you can stay in the air; know what this means in terms of distance with current winds (unless it's absolutely calm, your "radius of range" will form an ellipse, and you won't be at the center of it); and know which possible landing airports are available within it. *Any port in a storm.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably not.  Depending on how poor your planning was (or appeared to be) you may have nothing happen, have letter placed in your file (not a violation), receive a violation, have to make a 709 ride with a Fed, or have your cert suspended, or maybe even a combination of some of these.

If you were a real goober and just went flying without checking fuel, and then lied about checking fuel, and then get caught lying to federal investigators then, yeah, revocation is a realistic possibility.  They don't like liars.  They can deal with stupid mistakes, but they will not tolerate a liar.

//thanks for the edit but was written as a runon//

Comment: There are very few instances of revocation, typically suspension with retraining is assigned to the offending pilot. Even when two airline pilots [missed their airport by 110 miles and ignored ATC for 90 minutes](http://www.nytimes.com/2009/10/27/us/27plane.html) had their licenses "revoked" but could [reapply for them after just 10 months](http://www.cnn.com/2010/TRAVEL/03/15/wayward.pilots.licenses/index.html) and taking all required tests/training for the licenses again.