# How many US airman's certificates are revoked, roughly, per year?

Tags: faa

There is a lot of literature devoted to FAA enforcement (see https://www.aopa.org/training-and-safety/pic-archive/faa-enforcement/faa-enforcement)

What is the threshold for revocation? The thing that specifically got me interested was a near collision runway video - assuming it wasn't an ATC/taxing instructions error, would this type of thing be sufficient? I'm also interested in what the appropriate penalty would be for that

Comment: Hello there, I see two questions: one in the question title and another in the question body. If you can edit the post to narrow down to one question, it would help you get a better answer.

Comment: Certificates are hardly ever permanently revoked completely. Usually they are suspended with conditions, like recurrent training and a ["709 Ride"](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1669/what-is-a-709-ride). For example the [pilots that got distracted and missed their destination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northwest_Airlines_Flight_188) (and ATC calls) initially had their licenses revoked, but they were allowed to reapply for them after 10 months.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[FAA Order 2150.3B](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/orders_notices/index.cfm/go/document.information/documentid/17213), Appendix B lists violations and the civil penalties (fines) and certificate actions which are to be imposed by the FAA. The rest of the document also discusses how investigations of certain violations are undertaken and thresholds. That order gives much more detail than you'd ever want to know.

A common theme is revocation is called for when the action is intentional.

These are what are the FAA initially charges you with, so they are higher than what actually happens. A certificate action is either negotiated as a settlement, or if it can't, it goes before an administrative law judge, then [appealed to the NTSB](https://www.ntsb.gov/legal/alj/Pages/airman_appeals.aspx), then appealed to the Federal court system.